Sizing the output capacitor of DC-DC convertor
My questions is continuation of my previous post:
Adding capacitors to the power stage of a DC-DC convertor (SEPIC&CUK)

My fist question is which capacitor in the circuit should be considered as output capacitor?


should I consider C4 and C9 as output capacitor? or C5 and C10. Then if C4 and C9 are the output capacitors, then what are the purpose of C5 and C10 and what is their affect in the circuit?

My second question is how we can assess the effect of changing the output capacitor in the control loop? (will it reduce or increase the bandwidth?)

In my previous post, I mentioned the need to modify the circuit to achieve a faster recovery time (less than 2-3 ms) when the load is applied. Based on my research, it’s clear that in addition to changing the output capacitor, it’s also necessary to adjust the compensation network, which determines the crossover frequency.
I'm seeking a reference document or guidance that provides a step-by-step approach for this process, including changing the output capacitor size, adjusting the compensation network, and ensuring circuit stability.

The output capacitors are (usually) by definition the capacitors in parallel with the load, i.e. on the output.  So C5 and C10.  Compensating Cuk and SEPIC converters can be challenging, they do have a RHP zero, so usually the easy route is to keep the loop bandwith fairly low.  You might be able to squeeze some more bandwidth out of the loop, or maybe just add enough output capacitance to support your load transient.

Also winding the two inductors on the same core has benefits for both topologies.  There's a good resource here: https://ridleyengineering.com/design-center-ridley-engineering/46-modeling/251-098-small-signal-modeling-of-the-tightly-coupled-sepic-converter.html
